# Curious... PHP pages rendered HTML flyout menu inactive?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have tried searching the database for a similar issue, but was unsuccessful in finding anything remotely close. I just noticed that the sub menu items on two pages on a site I am creating that use php or are php have stopped working. Nothing was changed on the menu items as they are library items that have not been detached from the original.

Instead of attaching the entire code for both pages (as they are quite long), I figured I would first provide a link to the testing server that the two pages in question are hosted on: (1) http://2142.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/apply_now.php and (2) http://2142.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/contact_us.htm.

If you think you know what is happening here, I would be very curious to know what it is and how to correct the issue (if there is a way to).

Any help would be appreciated. If you need to see the entire page source to figure this out, just let me know and I will edit the post to include it.

Thank you in advance.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Okay, so the solution that solved my problem was to do some additional troubleshooting. I had initially assumed the problem was only with the pages containing php, however I discovered that other html pages were also affected. So, I used one of the properly working pages and copied it as a test template. I used that template to copy paste my php code into and - voila - the menus worked again!

Just goes to show how easy it is to accidentally delete a closing div tag which is what I think I may have done.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: So what is broken?  Something client-side, or something server-side?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in this question as well. This will help future users with the same problem in future (since your URLs will no longer work). Thanks

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, can you describe how the page should work?

Comment: @JohnP, code is added now. I had to remove some of it because the post said it was too long. I only removed irrelevant info.

Comment: @Niels Bom, the sub menus located at the top and side are not working on the only two pages that contain php. The rest of the site which is html still works perfect. Menu items are controlled through a library item, so they were not accidentally changed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a simple system (like most websites) and things stop working there's a very high probability of it being caused by a change done by somebody working with the site. In investigating the causes for an error always look at the most probable causes first.  So: has anyone else done any programming (PHP) or front-end-work (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) on the site?

Comment: turns out you're right... it is something I did and it's not just the php pages as I originally assumed. Thank you.

Comment: @Leah It would help if you posted the solution for future reference. Thanks

Comment: If you work with a version control system (like Mercurial or Git) you can very easily see a list of the changes you made in all the files in your project. This can help in debugging. Getting started with version control is easy, if you're not using it yet I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ddsmoothmenu.init({mainmenuid: "smoothmenu2", orientation: 'v', classname: 'ddsmoothmenu-v', contentsource: "markup" })</script>
```

AFTER your menu, not before.

Comment: tried it... didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following errors happen in the pages that the menu doesn't work. I think your JS might be malformed or broken on the pages that have the broken menu

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: flashRootLocation is not defined
apply_now.php:80Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined
apply_now.php:307Uncaught ReferenceError: flashConfigLocation is not defined
apply_now.php:344Uncaught ReferenceError: flashConfigLocation is not defined
apply_now.php:383Uncaught ReferenceError: flashConfigLocation is not defined
apply_now.php:597Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined
```

Comment: so what does that mean? There is no flash used on this site...